# Eclipse C/C++ Compilation faile

Tags: c, eclipse

hi
I'm new to the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ developer(I'm using eclipse Helios for C/C++)
i've made a small program like as

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
printf("Hello Eclipse for C C++");
}
```

And when trying to run it, getting an error like "Launch failed. Binary not found"

though CDT for C/C++ already installed
can any body help me out?

Comment: Why aren't you using `int main()`?

Answer (score 1):

What C compiler are you using under the covers there? People who include `conio.h` are invariably using Turbo C - I don't know *why,* it's antiquated and you can get a much better free compiler (in terms of both cost *and* freedom) in `gcc` (should be pretty-well standard on any Linux distro, or get your hands on MinGW if you're running under Windows).

Try the following instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    printf("Hello Eclipse for C/C++\n");
    return 0;
}
```